# Finding a specific string in a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have the following list:

```
l={"apple","orange","kiwi","APPLE","lemon"}
```

How can I make a command so the capitalised word would be returned? 
So in this case the output should be

```
{"APPLE"}
```

Surely one can do `l[[4]]` but this is not what I am looking for, I want to have a command to search on a long list and return the capital words. Also note that in my case the whole word is in capital letter not only the first letter. **Also assume that I don't know what would be the capital word, I just know that I have a list and somewhere in it there is a capitalised letter word, I need to find those.**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
l = {"apple", "orange", "kiwi", "APPLE", "lemon", "Lemon", "leMon"};
Select[l, UpperCaseQ]
```

> {"APPLE"}

Comment: Ah, I need to recalibrate my *gedanken Mathematica*; I didn't know that plain `UpperCaseQ[]` will still work! :)

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
Select[l, StringMatchQ[__?UpperCaseQ]]
```